# $(window).bind not working for content loaded with ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
 $(window).bind('scroll', function(){ //when the user is scrolling...
  //some-code
  });
```

I face the same problem for click and I solved it this way:

```
$(document).on('click','#id',function(){
//some code
})
```

I dont know how to assign scroll action for content loaded with ajax.

http://www.arrowlife.com/index-v3

Comment: Why can't you use just: `$( window ).scroll(function() {` instead of trying to bind it ? Any specific reason

Comment: you shouldn't have to use delegation for event bind at window level. I think problem comes from: `//some-code`

Comment: This is not an issue, I can promise you that the window wasn't loaded with ajax.

Comment: @Onaseriousnote that's ok but i don't know where to look... And sorry, looks like i misread your previous comment, my bad!

Comment: try adding an alert inisde '$(window).bind('scroll', function(){' to see if it's getting executed. Also check console to see if there are any errors.

Comment: its not getting executed..i tried

Comment: Are you scrolling the window or some other element ?

Comment: the window..you can check the link...the initial two sections are working fine...observe the blue box with share and comment on the right side..you will know what i am talking about

Comment: you should post the relevant code `//some-code`  issue comes from here i'm quite sure, not from the event

Comment: just for ref    http://jsfiddle.net/K3sHF/

Comment: Your are not updating variable `preLbdata;` with new added elements

Answer (score 1):

try calling the function again after the ajax call

```
  $.ajax({ 
      //some code   
  }).done(function(){   
      //scroll function 
  });
```

I think the issue is that you are calling the function before the element exists and therefore is not working properly.

Comment: OP is using a global variable `preLbdata=$('.sldRhtbx');` which he never updates. He should update it when clicking on 'LOAD MORE' button once new element exists